# Redirecting when the querystring is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, asp.net-mvc-5

In my project I have two controllers for a bus service the bus routes and bus route stops. In order to access the route stops you need to select a bus route, if a route hasn't been selected I need to redirect back to the bus route index. I made an If else statement to check for a query string and cookie holding the information.
When I go directly to the bus route stop controller it should throw me back to the bus route list but it doesn't.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string busRouteCode = "";
            //checks query string to see if empty
            if (Request.QueryString == null)
            {
                //checks the cookies to see if empty
                if (Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"] == null)
                    { 
                    //if empty returns to bus route controller.
                     return View("index", "snBusRoutes");
                    }
                else
                    {
                        busRouteCode = Response.Cookies["busRouteCode"].Value;    
                    }                             
            }
            else 
            {
              busRouteCode = Request.QueryString["busRouteCode"];  
            }


            var routeStops = db.routeStops.Include(r => r.busRoute).Include(r => r.busStop);
            return View(routeStops.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString))

Comment: can I do that for the cookie as well?

Comment: the cookie value, yes, because it is a string.  The cookie itself, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Request.QueryString` *in its entirety* is ever going to be *null*.  Though a specific *value* may be null or empty.  Something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["busRouteCode"]))
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"]))
        return View("index", "snBusRoutes");
```

**Update:** Semantically it's probably better to perform a redirect than to return the view in this case.  The user is making a specific request, but that request directs them somewhere else.  They should know they're going somewhere else.  Something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["busRouteCode"]))
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Cookies["busRouteCode"]))
        return RedirectToAction("index", "controllerName");
```

Comment: Im crashing now when I click on the link to go to that controller. It comes up with    
 "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[snBusStop.Models.routeStop]'. "

Comment: @SteveN: Maybe your call to `View(string, string)` doesn't work?  I didn't change that, just copied what you had.  The error sounds like that view is expecting a collection, and you're not providing it with one.  Semantically it's probably better to use a redirect instead of returning the view anyway, I'll update the answer...

Comment: Thanks the RedirectToAction works. Much appreciated.